WordPress Viki Booking plugin
I'm creating a hotel website using WordPress and this is my 1st project that I'm using WordPress for development. I watched a few tutorials and started developing this.
For the booking part, I'm using the Viki Booking Plugin. Most of the parts I have completed. and got an issue, I don't know If I did something wrong when configuring the stage, but now if the booking dates are not available, it shows a section as Availability for the dates near selected dates. But that section duplicates on the view.
With this, I uploaded a GIF image of the section. Does anyone know how to stop duplicating this?

